# Talend .items or .properties file comparison across projects

Tags: version-control, talend

I have imported a existing Talend project. I wish to evaluate the migration of code from the previous project to the new project.

We have just modified values for the few of the context variable's in the jobs. We wish to evaluate are the jobs are of same sync in terms of code.

Any suggestions to compare the movement from our local Talend workspace in terms of `.items` or `.properties` file by taking one job as an example.

Comment: What does "evaluate are the jobs are of same sync in terms of code" mean? Which movement? What do you want to check?

Comment: Basically i want to check if all the components are the same in use or are there any additional components or custom java code changed as part of bug fix in the previous environment that is missed out to be cascaded to the new environment. In short, to verify if there are any delta piece of code in the previous environment and not in the latest environment.

Comment: You'd have to parse the XML file (.items), the properties files is no help for you I think. From the XML file focus on the component name, main settings, etc. You can use a tFileinputXML to do this, then map everything into database tables, and from there you can do the join.